# Custom Format for "constructors"

Tags: custom-notation

Say I have a the typical Mathematica linked list structure defined like so:

```
Attributes[Pair] = {HoldAllComplete};

Nil = Pair[];

Cons = Pair[#1, #2]&;
```

It's well-known that turning a regular `List` into a linked list is easy:

```
ToLinkedList[list_List] := Fold[Cons[#2, #1]&, Nil, Reverse@list];
```

With some caveats that aren't relevant to this problem, converting back to a regular list is even easier:

```
Pair /: Normal[p_Pair] := List @@ Flatten[p];
```

We can use this to make a "constructor":

```
LinkedList[args___] := ToLinkedList@{args};
```

Right now, the output looks pretty terrible

```
In[43]:= ToLinkedList@{1, 2, 3}
Out[43]= Pair[1, Pair[2, Pair[3, Pair[]]]]
```

It would be really nice if we could have output that looks like `LinkedList[1, 2, 3]` instead. Attempts to do simple things with `Format` have provided me with no joy. For instance this looks great:

```
Format[p : Pair[_, _]] := 
 Row[{"LinkedList", "[", Row[p // Normal, ","], "]"}, BaseStyle -> "Output"];
Format[Nil] := Row[{"Nil"}, BaseStyle -> "Output"]

In[45]:= LinkedList[1, 2, 3]
Out[45]= LinkedLits[1, 2, 3]
```

But it completely falls apart when you try to copy and paste. Indeed, I had to type the stuff after `Out` by hand, because when I tried to paste into the text area, what actually showed up was:

```
Row[{"LinkedList", "[", Row[{1, 2, 3}, ","], "]"}, 
 BaseStyle -> "Output"]
```

This was not really what I wanted. Cutting and pasting inside a notebook appears to work OK, but when I try to evaluate a pasted expression as input, I get awful stuff like this:

```
MakeExpression::boxfmt: InputForm in MakeExpression[FormBox[RowBox[{Row,[,RowBox[{RowBox[{<<3>>}],,,RowBox[{<<3>>}]}],]}],InputForm],InputForm] is not a box formatting type. A box formatting type is any member of $BoxForms. >>
```

I know I could use `MakeBoxes` to do what I want, but that only works for `StandardForm` or `TraditionalForm`, and this seems like a perfectly sensible textual representation. I have a feeling I'm using `Format` *completely wrong*, but I'm not sure what using it right looks like.

**EDIT** in response to rcollyer: I have tried the `` Notation` `` package, but it's box-oriented, and I can't figure out how to flatten out the `Pair` structures for outputting inside the `LinkedList`.

**EDIT** again in response to ruebenko: you're right; it's been fixed.

**EDIT** to fix an arguable bug in the implementation of `Normal` for `Pair`s, discovered while playing around trying to create a custom format. As it stands right now:

```
In[49]:= LinkedList[LinkedList[1, 2], LinkedList[3, 4], LinkedList[5, 6]]
Out[49]= LinkedList[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

I don't want this auto-flattening behavior for `Normal` in any event, but it's particularly terrible in the case of formatting output because the output is totally wrong. Here's a fix:

```
FromLinkedList[list_Pair] :=
  NestWhileList[List @@ #[[2]] &, {Null, list}, #[[2]] =!= Nil &][[2 ;;, 1]];

Pair /: Normal[p_Pair] := List @@ FromLinkedList[p]
```

This is a bit uglier, especially that `Null` placeholder at the beginning, but it does the right thing:

```
In[63]:= LinkedList[LinkedList[1, 2], LinkedList[3, 4], LinkedList[5, 6]]
Out[63]= LinkedList[LinkedList[1, 2], LinkedList[3, 4], LinkedList[5, 6]]
```

It's the best I could come up with; other solutions involved `Reap` and `Sow`, which seemed like a real shame when working with a nice functional data structure like this one.

Comment: Have you tried to use the ``Notations` `` package for this?

Comment: I think your definition should look like this: `ToLinkedList[list_List] := Fold[Cons[#2, #1] &, Nil, Reverse@list];` otherwise I am not sure what you would like to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some further thought and exploration, it seems like this is a perfect use of the newish (version 6 and up) [`Defer` wrapper](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Defer.html). Adding the following rules to `Pair` seems to do exactly what I'm looking for:

```
Pair /: Format[list : Pair[_, _]] :=
  With[{args = Normal@list},
   Defer[LinkedList[##]] & @@ args];
Pair /: Format[Pair[]] := Defer[Nil];
```

Then:

```
In[33]:= Pair[]
Out[33]= Nil

In[34]:= LinkedList["wongle", bongle, "bingle", fringle]
Out[34]= LinkedList["wongle", bongle, "bingle", fringle]

In[35]:= LinkedList["wongle", bongle, "bingle", fringle] // InputForm
Out[34]= Pair["wongle", Pair[bongle, Pair["bingle", Pair[fringle, Pair[]]]]]
```

This time I *was* able to cut and paste directly from the `Out` cells; indeed, a little investigation with "Show Cell Contents" suggests that there isn't anything weird going on in those cells at all.

Answer (score 5):

I see in your question that you would rather not use `MakeBoxes` but I think this might be worth a try.

```
Pair /: MakeBoxes[linkedList : Pair[i_, p_Pair], fmt_] := 
 TagBox[ToBoxes[LinkedList @@ Flatten[linkedList]], 
  InterpretTemplate[Pair[i, p] &], Editable -> False, 
  Selectable -> True, SelectWithContents -> True]
```

The `InterpretTemplate` affects how Mathematica will see your expression whereas the [`TagBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TagBox.html) is how you will see it.

This allows for copy and paste and any of the various forms work just fine.

Comment: Andy, `InterpretTemplate` does not show up in the docs. Do you have any other pointers on its use?

Comment: @rcollyer no more than what I've shown here.  It is usually a game of trial and error for me. On that note. I would use it cautiously since undocumented functions may not stick around :)

Comment: I'm generally not a fan of undocumented features for exactly those reasons. But, if it works.